# compilation issue : libvlc exception t is missing

Tags: qt, include, libvlc

I'm trying to mix `Qt` and `libVLC`, I've downloaded libs, tried some tutorials, but I always stop on the same error and I can't find any solution in Google...

Here's the compilation output

```
error: unknown type name 'libvlc_exception_t'; did you mean 'libvlc_event_t'?
```

I'm running `MacOS 10.8.4`

**EDIT :** the libvlc_exception_t is not even documented on [LibVLC Doc](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html)

Comment: Which version of VLC/libVLC are you using?

Comment: @Morwenn I'm using VLC 2.0.6

Comment: `libvlc_exception_t` should be in `<vlc/libvlc_structures.h>` which should be included by `<vlc/libvlc.h>`. You'd better check whether it is done right :)

Comment: even by including `<vlc/libvlc_structures.h>` manually it doesn't work... (mine is 77 lines long... seems short)

Comment: and there isn't any line mentioning `libvlc_exception_t`

Comment: And mine is quite the same as this one : https://github.com/kermit666/vlc/blob/master/include/vlc/libvlc_structures.h

Comment: by the way, what's the size of your `<vlc/libvlc_structures.h>` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why :

> doc/ChangeLog-2010:    The libvlc_exceptions have been removed from libvlc.

Comment: Actually, you can find [the corresponding commit](https://github.com/kermit666/vlc/commit/dd1e8bad853c63c7df40ba28ae62137fc8e5001a) on Github.