# libvlc exceptions handling

Tags: libvlc

Due to [compilation issue : libvlc exception t is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088910/compilation-issue-libvlc-exception-t-is-missing) I know that there's no more method like `libvlc_exception` in libvlc library. Anyway i need to handle exceptions somehow. In my program I need to show playlist which contains mjpg stream from IP camera. If camera is not available I can see error messages in my stdout like

```
[0xb1c00b48] acces_http access error: cannot connect to 10.1.1.61:80
```

I have tried to print `libvlc_errmsg()` after every action which uses libvlc but it returns null. Is there any other way to handle exceptions from VLC?

@Edit:
Additional info: my global error handler also does not recieve any of those messages;

Comment: According the other post, there are no exceptions anymore in libvlc, so which exceptions do you want to handle? Or do you mean errors in general?

Comment: I need to handle errors that are probably invoked not in the moment of calling any of the libvlc function. For example connection to host timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the function `libvlc_media_get_state (libvlc_media_t *p_md)` and `libvlc_media_player_get_state (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)` to see in which state your objects are. For example for the cannot connect to ip address, the get_state will return 7(ERROR) while on the successfull stream you will get a 3(PLAYING). Keep in mind that they dont change immediately and you will have to implement some kinf of polling.